# Wrecked grub for encrypted system boot; got it back but now it is very slow

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, boot

Sequence of events:

- Running ubuntu 20.04 with encryption on work laptop
- Booted with external usb (Pop-OS 20.04) to run personal stuff
- That boot prompted firmware update
- BIG MISTAKE: Ran firmware update (was BIOS update), probably didn't do the sequence correctly
- On reboot: blue screen from something Windows saying can't boot with error code 0xc00000e
- After long debugging and commandline grub, found this gist: https://gist.github.com/samuelcolvin/43c5ed2807e7db004b1058d0c9bfb068
- Followed it closely, replaced drives for my setup ( `nvme0n1`).
- GOT MY BOOT and SYSTEM BACK! but.....

Now it boots very slow compared to before (SSD!).
`sudo systemd-analyze                                                                                                                                                                                                    Startup finished in 19.544s (firmware) + 13.302s (loader) + 13.646s (kernel) + 1min 38.111s (userspace) = 2min 24.604s`

Any idea what I could try to get a swift boot back?

EDIT: Output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 38.139s
└─multi-user.target @1min 38.139s
  └─docker.service @1min 36.961s +1.177s
    └─network-online.target @1min 36.960s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.658s +6.302s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.583s +73ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.581s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.574s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.574s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 30.574s +594us
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.570s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1min 30.450s +119ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1min 30.430s +18ms
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @335ms +134ms
                          └─systemd-journald.service @267ms +66ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @264ms
                              └─system.slice @261ms
                                └─-.slice @261ms
```

Is it `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` it seems?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think I was able to solve it myself...sorry for verbosity, but maybe it might be of use for someone some day...

I first found some help about the tmpfiles setup, recommending to clean up the /tmp dir. I did that, but rebooting still was slow.

I then actually found this:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=243029

And the last comment there was the important find: My UUIDs were messed up due to my rescue attempts - actually, only the `/boot/efi` entry was. Fortunately the original one was still there and just commented out. I re-enabled it and - voilá: I have a speedy boot back.